# Using button in Android to call an activity and a web service

Tags: android, web-services, button, android-activity

I want to know whether a single button in Android can call a web service as well as start another activity i.e move to another splash screen when pressed.

Is this possible ? Can a single button have two Events ? If yes,how ?

Comment: the onClick can do just about anything you want it to. For my app, I used a button to clear a few EditTexts, and another button was used to grab text from all the fields, call a method to do a search with them, and then load the activity to display the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A button can have only one `ClickListener` but you call a web service and start an activity from this listener.

**EDIT**:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        callWebService();
        startAnotherActivity();
    }
});
```

Comment: so u mean a single ClickListener object can help me call any number of web services and activities I want to in my project or is limited to something ?

Comment: You can add any logic to this listener. It acts like any other part of your code.

Comment: And what abt the timing ? Will the application close unexpectedly since it would find two different calls on the same button ..how to ensure that the web srevice is called first and then the another activity and vice versa ?

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand the problem. I've added a code sample to the answer.